# setting up join table in Rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

so I'm new to join tables. I'm not sure if that's even what I need. This is my current setup and situation:
I have 2 user models.

```
Company
User
```

I need to create a table that belongs to the company model, but can be answered by the User model. Each company can have several applications thus I called my 3rd model

```
Application
```

so far I've done

```
class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :company
end
```

and

```
Class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :applications
end
```

I created the application model straight forward by running:

```
rails g model application
```

have I already made some mistakes, or am I doing fine so far? and what are the next steps here.

Comment: It seems to be fine so far. Next step would be reading a nice tutorial to get to know the application flow you can try to go with http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ and http://www.railstutorial.org/book for the starters.

Answer (score 1):

Seems good so far

--

**Join Tables**

There are two types of join table - [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) & [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

[image]

They do the same thing (create a `many-to-many` relationship), which means you can call `@model.objects` *through* the `join model`

From reading your information, it looks like you could do this:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :applications
   has_many :companies, through: :applications
end

#app/models/application.rb
Class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields - id | user_id | company_id | etc | etc | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :company
   belongs_to :user
end

#app/models/company.rb
Class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :applications
   has_many :users, through: :applications
end
```

Comment: I'm struggling with how to structure my database. So far I've come to add the company_id on the post. But my problem is this:

A company has_many applications. They submit info like interview questions. Which will then be displayed in the show of that application, to users. The users will answer those questions and submit. 

So the applications belongs to the company, but needs to keep track of the ID of which user that answered the questions. Visible by the company